# Subir archivos a Owncloud desde web

Tags: javascript, php, api, fileupload

Tengo que subir archivos desde una pagina web por medio de js, no se si haya alguna api propia de owncloud o algo, no encuentro endpoints, owncloud esta en el mismo servidor en que esta alojado el sitio en wordpress, pero, no se si sea posible, ayuda, no encuentro información que me sirva.